# ggplot: fill the box plots with the color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with the rates from which I do box plots grouped by version. I want to color each box by a device. I also have another data2 that contains the numbers I want to display for each `version`. However, it seems that my geom_box has conflicts with it.
It shows me an error:
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Object 'device' not found

```
  p <- ggplot(data1, aes(factor(version),rates,fill=device))
  p + geom_boxplot() + geom_text(data = data2, aes(x = version, y = 0, label = count))
```

data1:

```
                   rates                  version                      device
1                     0.56            Windows/desktop/Chrome              desktop
2                     0.13          iOS/mobile/Safari mobile               mobile
3                     0.15          iOS/tablet/Safari mobile               tablet
4                     0.65           Windows/desktop/Firefox              desktop
5                     0.17               OS X/desktop/Safari              desktop
6                     0.83            Windows/desktop/Chrome              desktop
7                     0.39           Windows/desktop/Firefox              desktop
8                     0.63            Windows/desktop/Chrome              desktop
9                     0.61 Windows/desktop/Internet Explorer              desktop
10                    0.00            Windows/desktop/Chrome              desktop
```

data2:

```
                                 version count
21188           iOS/mobile/Safari mobile 37545
105488           Windows/desktop/Firefox 28030
82478             Windows/desktop/Chrome 23936
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(factor(version),rates)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=device) + 
  geom_text(data = data2, aes(x = version, y = 0, label = count))
```

It is trying to find the `fill` variable in `data2`, but it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data <- merge(data1, data2, by='version', all=TRUE)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(version,rates,fill=device))
p + geom_boxplot() + geom_text(aes(x = version, y = 0, label = count))
```

with output:

[image]